# Laravel 5.6 | Display list items horizontally, not vertically

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to display member details horizontally and not vertically.

My foreach code in my index.blade.php file:

```
@foreach($member as $members)
    <a href="{{url('members',array($members->id))}}">
        <p>{{$members->name}}</p>
        <p>{{$members->surname}}</p>
        <p>{{$members->id_number}}</p>
        <p>Submitted on: {{$members->created_at}}</p>
    </a>
@endforeach
```

So I want name, surname and ID number to display next to each other, i.e. I want each member on 1 line. Currently it display vertically like so...

[image]

I can't find any docs on how to change the display.

Comment: Seriously? Put all data in one `<p>`.

Comment: Don't seperate them with `<p>`s. Seperate them before/after your `<a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're explicitly seperating each `$members` field using paragraphs (`<p>`). Use this to seperate each of your items into a `<div>`:

```
<?php
@foreach($member as $members)
<div>
    <a href="{{url('members',array($members->id))}}">
        {{$members->name}} {{$members->surname}},
        {{$members->id_number}}, 
        Submitted on: {{$members->created_at}}
    </a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Of course this is the answer, I guess I must take a break. Thanks